# How can I change all the device IDs on my quad port Intel NIC (Ubuntu 16.04 and ethtool)?

Tags: ethernet

So I have a quadport Intel gigabite NIC (dual 82571EB).

To get the device IDs, I used:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ lspci -nn -vvv | grep Ethernet
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:10bc] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:000a]
03:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:10bc] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:000a]
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:10bc] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:000a]
04:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:10bc] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:000a]
```

all the 4 devices were identified as 8086:10bc. **I want to change 10bc to 105e for all 4 devices.**

ifconfig shows all 4 devices as:

```
enp3s0f0 enp3s0f1 enp4s0f0 enp4s0f1
```

To find the correct offset, I used this command:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ ethtool -e my-interface-here | grep 86

0x0010 87 d9 05 71 2f 24 4b 70 3c 10 bc 10 86 80 65 b3
```

Running the command above for all 4 interfaces gave me the same result.

I made a backup of the EEPROM for all interfaces using:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ ethtool -e my-interface-here raw on > my-interface-here.bin
```

To actually make the change, I used this command:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ ethtool -E enp3s0f0 magic 0x10bc8086 offset 0x001a value 0x001a value 0x5e
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ ethtool -E enp3s0f1 magic 0x10bc8086 offset 0x001a value 0x001a value 0x5e
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ ethtool -E enp4s0f0 magic 0x10bc8086 offset 0x001a value 0x001a value 0x5e
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ ethtool -E enp4s0f1 magic 0x10bc8086 offset 0x001a value 0x001a value 0x5e
```

**Observations/issues:**

After rebooting machine, I ran

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ lspci -nn -vvv | grep Ethernet
    xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ lspci -nn -vvv | grep Ethernet
    03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:10bc] (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:000a]
    03:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller [8086:105e] (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller [8086:000a]
    04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:10bc] (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:000a]
    04:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller [8086:105e] (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller [8086:000a]
```

and it shows only 2 device IDs have changed.

I moved the network cable to all 4 ports and I can browse the internet without any problems. This happened after rebooting.

Any suggestions on how to change all device IDs to 105e? thanks

Comment: So, after the reboot, which two of the four had their IDs changed? Why do you want to change the IDs anyway? Since the NICs show up to the system, it seems that your driver identifies them just fine (and if it didn't, `ethtool` likely wouldn't work on them). Point 5 says all interfaces work in the end, so didn't they work before or is this significant in some other way?

Comment: I was only using Xubuntu as it's the only way I know when it comes to changing device IDs. BUT I won't be using Xubuntu once I got it working. Thanks

Comment: ah, you are planning to use some other system that only recognises the other PCI ID for the cards? Would it be possible to solve the problem at the other end by adding the ID 0x10bc to the driver, instead of changing it on the adapters? Depends on what that other system would be, of course...

Comment: Ah, there's the list of IDs after the reboot, didn't see that before my comment. So since the only the first unit of each chip changed IDs, one would guess that the second ID comes from somewhere else... I wonder if the datasheet for the chip would tell?